# Why does not adding distinct in this query produce duplicate rows?

Tags: postgresql

This query was taken from a Rails application log...I'm trying to edit a massive postgresql statement I didn't write....If I don't add a *distinct* keyword after the *SELECT*, 2 duplicate rows appear for each braintree account.  Why is this and is there another way to avoid having to use the *distinct* to avoid duplicates?

EDIT: I understand what distinct is supposed to do, the reason I'm asking is that it doesn't generate duplicates for other toy lines.  By other toy lines, this query is building a "table" for a particular toy id (this specific example toys.id = 12).  How do I figure out where the duplicate rows are being generated?

```
     SELECT accounts.braintree_account_id as braintree_account_id, 
                                    accounts.braintree_account_id as braintree_account_id, format('%s %s', addresses.first_name, 
                                addresses.last_name) as shipping_address_full_name, 
                            users.email as email, addresses.line_1 as shipping_address_line_1, 
                            addresses.line_2 as shipping_address_line_2, addresses.city as 
                            shipping_address_city, addresses.state as shipping_address_state,

                                    addresses.zip as shipping_address_zip_code, addresses.country
                         as shipping_address_country, CASE WHEN xy_shirt IS NULL THEN '' ELSE xy_shirt END, plans.name as plan_name, toys.sku as sku, to_char(accounts.created_at, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS') as 
                        account_created_at, 
                    to_char(accounts.next_assessment_at, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS') as account_next_assessment_at, 
                        accounts.account_status as account_status FROM \"accounts\" INNER JOIN \"addresses\" ON 
                                    \"addresses\".\"id\" = \"accounts\".\"shipping_address_id\" AND \"addresses\".\"type\" IN 
                    ('ShippingAddress') LEFT OUTER JOIN shipping_methods ON 
                    shipping_methods.account_id = accounts.id LEFT OUTER JOIN plans ON 

accounts.plan_id = plans.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON                          
accounts.user_id = users.id LEFT OUTER JOIN toys ON plans.toy_id = toys.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN account_variations ON accounts.id = 
account_variations.account_id LEFT OUTER JOIN variations ON 
account_variations.variation_id = variations.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                        choice_value_variations ON variations.id = 
                        choice_value_variations.variation_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN choice_values ON 
                        choice_value_variations.choice_value_id = choice_values.id LEFT OUTER 
                        JOIN choice_types ON choice_values.choice_type_id = choice_types.id 
                    LEFT 
                        OUTER JOIN choice_type_toys ON choice_type_toys.toy_id = toys.id 
    AND choice_type_toys.choice_type_id = choice_types.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM crosstab('SELECT accounts.id, choice_types.id, 
    choice_values.presentation FROM accounts\n                
        LEFT JOIN account_variations ON 
    accounts.id=account_variations.account_id\n                
        LEFT JOIN variations ON account_variations.variation_id=variations.id\n                
        LEFT JOIN choice_value_variations ON 
        variations.id=choice_value_variations.variation_id\n                
        LEFT JOIN choice_values ON 
        choice_value_variations.choice_value_id=choice_values.id\n                
        LEFT JOIN choice_types ON choice_values.choice_type_id=choice_types.id 
        ORDER BY 1,2',\n                       'select distinct choice_types.id 
        from choice_types JOIN choice_values ON choice_values.choice_type_id = 
        choice_types.id JOIN choice_value_variations ON 
        choice_value_variations.choice_value_id = choice_values.id JOIN 
        variations ON choice_value_variations.variation_id = variations.id JOIN choice_type_toys ON choice_type_toys.choice_type_id = choice_types.id JOIN toys ON toys.id = choice_type_toys.toy_id 
            where toys.id=12 ORDER 
                BY choice_types.id ASC')\n                
        AS (account_id int, xy_shirt 
                VARCHAR)) account_variation_view\n          ON 
                accounts.id=account_variation_view.account_id WHERE 
                \"accounts\".\"account_status\" = 'active' AND 
                \"addresses\".\"flagged_invalid_at\" IS NULL AND \"toys\".\"id\" = 12 
                AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT \"account_skipped_months\".* FROM 
                \"account_skipped_months\" WHERE 
                \"account_skipped_months\".\"month_year\" = 'JUL2016' AND 
                (account_skipped_months.account_id = accounts.id)))"
```

Comment: Evaluating this code is made more difficult by the lack of formatting.  As the answer below states, distinct will be required in order to remove duplicates.  Duplication occurs <generally> when a primary or master table is related to more than one row elsewhere.

Comment: Is there an easy way to format non-line-breaked SQL when you are copying and pasting into StackOverflow?

Comment: No.  Unfortunately you have to do it manually.  As to your original question, it is likely that one or more of your joined tables has more than one row for the account.  I would first look at the inline views you have - selects within the where clause.  Hard to diagnose without debugging each join.  But the only way some would be duplicated and others not would be because for one join or another there are two rows.  I might take the braintree_account_id that is causing problems and debug through the queries by adding it to the appropriate where clause.

Comment: @Nona Can you clarify what you mean by "other toy lines"?

Comment: Please don't take this as a scold, but your initial question left the reader with the impression that "distinct" wasn't understood.  I am leveling the field a bit for Shayna.  Nuance in text is difficult - witness emojis - and easily misconstrued, so no blame attached.

Comment: thanks @TGray, I realized it was a bit unclear.

Comment: @Shayna, I edited the above - I'm generating tables for different toy ids

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using DISTINCT in a SELECT statement is to eliminate duplicate rows.